# Calling rowToggle on Page Load using Prime Faces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.5, the latest release for our development work!  In our homepage, we display the rows of data. When we click a row `onRowSelect` (`SelectEvent`) event we navigate to the next page with the `Navigation Handler`. On this landing page, I have a `dataTable` with expandable rows which has data in it.  When I click the `rowToggle` icon the data is displayed in row expansion section (as it should normally).

What I need is to show the data automatically when page is loaded, with the `rowToggler` displaying down.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using a bit of JavaScript (jQuery).  All you have to do, is as your page loads call the `click` action of the `RowExpander`.

Something like this would work :

```js
jQuery('.ui-row-toggler').click()
```

You can place this in your `body` `onLoad` attribute.

#### Source

- http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8537